# Check if the internal dictionary in a dictionary of dictionaries contains a value

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dictionary

My code converts a json file in to a dictionary of dictionaries where the value is a class I built.

This is the class:

```
public class JsonPart
{
    public string sql { get; set; }
    public string oracle { get; set; }
    public List<string> Hebrew { get; set; }
}
```

This is the dictionary I am converting to:

```
  public static  Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, JsonPart>> j;
```

I want to check if the dictionary contains a specific key where the value is a dictionary how's key I know and in the value (class `JsonPart`) under the list named Hebrew there is the word I am looking for.

For example external key is "MandatoryWords", internal key is "select", and the list Hebrew contains the word "בחר".

I need to check the whole path and not just the last word as the dictionary is only built while running and I do not know if it really contains these keys.

Even if I assume these keys exist in the dictionary how do I access them if the dictionary is only built while running?

Comment: What exactly is your problem here? Look up `j.TryGetValue("MandatoryWords", out k)` and if it suceeds, look up `k.TryGetValue("select", out l)` and if it succeeds check `l.Hebrew.Contains("בחר")`. Or did I get you wrong?

Comment: So easy I did not think of it thank you very much

Comment: who wants to throw Klaus' response into a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but do you mean you are given an external key, an internal key and a word in Hebrew, and you want to check if this combination exists in the dictionary?

Then you could do this:

```
public static bool Check(string externalKey, string internalKey, string word) {
   if (j.TryGetValue(externalKey, out var innerDic))
   {
       if (innerDic.TryGetValue(internalKey, out var jsonPart))
       {
           return jsonPart.Hebrew.Contains(word);
       }
   }
   return false;
}
```